# Book about 3 interstellar probes with human brains

Tags: story-identification

Story revolves around 3 interstellar probes with human brains. I think they ( or one of them) escaped a government facility before they were "ready".  Biggest part that I remember is that the main character that is chasing the probes visits a scientist that had something to do with the building of the probes. The scientist has genetically engineered a flower to have a human face and vocal cords. And when the scientist shines light on, or activates, the plant sings a beautiful song.  Don't remember much else.

- I think it was a full novel
- Most likely late 80s or early 90s
- Written in English - possibly American

Comment: Is it a full novel, novella or short story? How old is it/when did you read it? What nationality/language was it?

Comment: I think it's a full novel. I want to says its from the early 90s. But could be 80s. English language. I believe it was an American novel. I read it last decade sometime

Comment: I've added that info to the question, and tried to make the title more descriptive. Feel free to rollback or remove any edits I've made.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wonder if it could be The Mind Pool by Charles Sheffield, published 1993.

The flower was engineered by a scientist called The Margrave aka Fujitsu:

> The Margrave stared at them gloomily and nodded. He closed the door and triple-locked it, then turned and pressed a light switch. At the other side of the room sat a bulbous plant, five feet high and about two feet across. When the light went on the leaves of the swollen upper part began to open. In less than thirty seconds a single vast flower was
>   revealed. Its central part resembled a human face, with pink cheeks, curved red mouth, and blind blue eyes. After a few moments, the mouth opened. A thin, beautiful tone came forth, a crystalline, pure soprano singing a wordless lament. The song continued and broadened, from a simple theme through to a complex coloratura embroidery.

The instellar probes are called Morgan Constructs. They were designed to explore the universe, but something went wrong and they turned out to be hostile to all life forms. There were seventeen of them originally but fourteen were destroyed in their escape attempt leaving the three you mention, though two were subsequently killed. The rest of the book is about the hunt for the last construct.

Comment: Yes!  The mind pool! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Could it be Destination Void (Frank Herbert)?

Comment: Can you explain why you think it might be this...

Comment: In his defense, it involves 3 human brains controlling a spaceship. It lacks the rest of details. :)

Comment: :) doubt it. 3 ships and each has 1 brain.